# Android - Show image from res/drawable onClick

Tags: android

First of all, I wanna say I've been seeking for an answer on the Forum and I found didn't match for what I wanted. Basically, what I want is: when the user clicks on one of the images previously "specified" on the .xml file, a new image is displayed on the center of the screen that is not "specified" on the .xml file. I wrote "specified" cause idk if it's the correct way to refer to this.

EDIT: there was no need to not specify the image previously, all I needed was to set "gone" for visibiity. This code is working exactly how I wanted (ty guys):

Main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Principal extends Activity {
    ImageView cuia1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        cuia1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cuia1);
        cuia1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView cuia1grande = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cuia1grande);
                cuia1grande.setVisibility(1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principal, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent">  

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*">   

    <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/tabelaCuias"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center">    

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/selecionaCuia"  
            android:text="Selecione a cuia"  
            android:textStyle="bold">            
        </TextView>  

        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/cuia1"  
            android:src="@drawable/cuia1">            
        </ImageView>  

        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/cuia2"  
            android:src="@drawable/cuia2">            
        </ImageView>  

        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/cuia3"  
            android:src="@drawable/cuia3">            
        </ImageView>  

        <ImageView  
            android:id="@+id/cuia4"  
            android:src="@drawable/cuia4">            
        </ImageView>                         
    </TableRow>  
</TableLayout>

<ImageView  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/cuia1grande"  
    android:src="@drawable/cuia1grande">            
</ImageView>
```

Comment: So you want the same image to be displayed on top of the other windows, or a different image all together?

Comment: A different image should be displayed on the center of screen when I click on one of the images already displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't want to "specify" the image in your layout file? You could place it there and not display it (`visibilty="gone"`), and then show/hide it when you deem fit.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Make your layout a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `TableLayout` (this will make things easier for showing the image in the center)
2. Place your `TableLayout` within the wrapping `RelativeLayout`
3. Define an `ImageView` as the last child within the wrapping `RelativeLayout`, set `centerInParent="true"`, `visibilty="gone"`
4. In your `onClick` method, simply set its `visibility` as `visible`.

If you really don't want to define the `ImageView` in the layout, then you can create it programmatically:

1. Follow the same steps 1-2 as before
2. Capture the reference to the wrapping `RelativeLayout` in the code
3. In the `onClick` method, create the `ImageView` programatically, specifying the `centerInParent="true"` via the code (let me know if you want an example on how to do this & I'll edit the answer with a code sample).
4. Add the new view to the `RelativeLayout` via `myRelativeLayout.addView(myImageView);`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna follow your tips and see what happens.

Comment: YES! That definitively solved.. I'm gonna post how the code is now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Principal extends Activity {
    ImageView cuia1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        cuia1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cuia1);
        //set invisible
        cuia1 .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cuia1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //show image on the center of screen  
                //set image
                cuia1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cuia1);
                // set visible
                cuia1 .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principal, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

import `import android.view.View;`

Cheerz!